# Cannot make a post request without using getResponse()

Tags: android, httpurlconnection, response-time

I'm using HttpURLConnection to post on an Azure server. The request succeed only if I want back the response code from the server.

```
private void PostStateSync(ProxyState mData) throws Exception
{
    GsonBuilder gsonBuilder= new GsonBuilder();
    gsonBuilder.serializeNulls();
    String json = gsonBuilder.create().toJson(mData);

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    URL object = new URL(ComURL);
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) object.openConnection();

    connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

    connection.setReadTimeout(15000);
    connection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setDoInput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");

    OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    bufferedWriter.write(json);
    bufferedWriter.flush();
    bufferedWriter.close();
    connection.connect();

    connection.getResponseCode();
    Log.v("Response state",String.valueOf(mStatus));

    Log.v("Response state","send");
}
```

In this case the request works but I have latency problem cause the server has low performance. In order to improve the request time I tried to comment `connection.getResponseCode();`

If I comment:

> connection.getResponseCode();
>           Log.v("Response state",String.valueOf(mStatus));

The post request doesn't work (I'm not receiving any errors or warn in logcat).

This is the Thread where I put the request. (I receive data every 15 seconds in proxystatelist). What I'm missing?

```
    private void StartSendState()
{
    SendStateWorkerThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (canSendRun)
            {
                try {
                ProxyState proxyState;
                synchronized (proxyStateList) {
                    proxyState = proxyStateList.peek();
                }
                if (proxyState!=null) {
                    PostStateSync(proxyState);
                }
                    synchronized (proxyStateList)
                    {
                  proxyStateList.poll();
                }
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
    SendStateWorkerThread.start();
}
```

Comment: You could also call `connection.getInputStream()`, but I'm not sure why commenting the response code would make anything faster. Obtaining an integer value from an already fetched response object won't really have a big speed improvement

Comment: I agree with you but why not getting the response my request doesn't work? This is weird

Comment: I had a project that I found the same issue, but I just accepted that I needed to get the response code, and it allowed for throwing errors whenever it was in the 400s